# CustomVisualizer extension in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

We are using a C++ visualizer which visualized the class content to DataTip using IDkmCustomVisualizer. Something what natvis already has but more advanced. The extension is written in C# and worked beautifully in VS 2017. Since we switched to VS 2019 it stopped working due to new mechanism introduced in VS 2019 (external process).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/visual-cpp-custom-visualizer-compatibility?view=vs-2019

Of course if I disable the "Load debug symbols in external process (native only)" option in VS my extension starts to work. However our project is huge and we like the new external process mechanism.

I also tried to add WorkerProcessSupported="true" to my vsdconfigxml. Based on:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Worker-Process-Remoting

However my visualizer is not called. I was not even able to get work the provided C++ extension example:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Cpp-Custom-Visualizer-Sample

The Worker-Process-Remoting code mentioned to split my class. Unfortunately without any example/tutorial I'm not able to do it.

Any advice how to solve this?
Many thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Maybe you could get some help from [Mads' blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/).

Comment: Thanks! I used that block as well to get my extension load to VS 2019. My extension used the synchronized Package and in VS 2019 it is necessary to load the extension using asynchronous Package. That part is solved - my extension loads to VS 2019 and the extension commands work well. However the debugger custom evaluator is still a problem. :-(

Comment: For Worker Process Remoting:-1.Get the sample C++ Visualizer working
-2.Add the WorkerProcessSupported="true" in the vsdconfig xml.
-3.Make it work with out of proc symbol loading in VS 2019
-4.See what the difference is between the example and yours.-5.You might also just start with turning this on:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ConcordExtensibilitySamples/wiki/Getting-troubleshooting-logs